# Automorphism sends primitive nth root of unity to primitive nth root of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'am now studying Hungerford's Algebra, p.306, Proposition 9.6 but I stucked at some statement.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to prove the underlined statement.
First let $R_{p}$ := { $p$-th root of unity in $N$ }. Since $char K$ does not divides $p$ (as in the proof of the proposition 9.6), by the remark in the above image, the $R_{p}$ has order $p$.

Let $\sigma \in Aut_{M}N$. Then $\sigma(\zeta)^p = 1_{N}$, so  $\sigma(\zeta) \in R_{p}$.

By the Lagrange theorem, $|<\sigma (\zeta)>|$ divides $|R_{p}|$, which is prime $p$. So $|<\sigma (\zeta)>| = p$ and $\sigma (\zeta)$ is primitive $p$-th root of unity. So it is of the form $\sigma (\zeta)= \zeta^{k}$ for some $1 \le k < p$. But can $\zeta^{k}$ be different from $\zeta$?

Or, is there any other method to prove that $\theta$ (as in the proof of proposition 9.6) is monomorphism? e.g., only assuming $\sigma (\zeta)= \zeta^{k}$ ?

Comment: $\mathrm{Aut}_M N$ is the set (group) of automorphisms of $N$ that fix(=act as the identity on) $M$ and $\sigma$ is such an automorphism. since $\zeta\in M$ we have $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta$

Comment: Wow, O.K.  :) thanks ! It is easy than I expected